# Vim does not accept Leader key - timeout set, remapped to ",", but yet only beeps

Tags: vim, leader

I'm new to Vim and currently having issues with my Leader key in MacVim on OSX 10.7, freshly installed.

I've tried remapping the Leader key to ",", using

> let mapleader=","

(in my .vimrc file, at its very top), increased the timeout (to 10000ms). I also activated

> set showcmd

To see if it, at all, fires - but it doesnt.

> :verbose map ,

does, interestingly, report "no mapping found".

Comment: a) What does `echo mapleader` in a running session say? b) what does `map` show (are you sure there are *any* leader mappings: it is fresh install after all)?

Comment: Why did you set the timeout to 10s? What is the link between the leader key and `showcmd`? What do you expect, exactly? The leader key does nothing by itself And *you* are supposed to create mappings using it.

Comment: Issue resolved - it was the fresh install that deactivated the filetype plugin, hence, there were no mappings at all. Thanks, guys!

Comment: @romainl At least netrw has leader mappings out-of-the-box (well, only netrw and changelog and man filetype plugins, total five or six mappings in the whole `/usr/share/vim/vim73`, depending on how you count changelog ones, no non-`<buffer>` mappings). This is exactly why I asked to check `:map` output: these mappings are so rare in fresh install. First two your questions are easily answerable: 1) to have enough time to find `<Leader>` key in the command line 2) because if you set `showcmd` this key will be shown in the command line while waiting for next key.

Comment: @fabianh11 : you should transform your comment into an answer, and approve it. This way the question will be considered "answered".

Comment: I am having the same problem. How did you activate the filetype plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved - it was my fresh install of everything that simply deactivated the filetype plugin. Hence, there were no mappings at all.

I reactivated the filetype plugin by adding

```
filetype plugin on
```

to my `.vimrc` file.